# Android resource not found exception?

Tags: java, android

I am having a strange problem using findViewById(id). It comes back with resource not found even though the resource is definitely there. It is a textview in a layout next to another textview, one of the textviews I can find by id but the other shows resource not found. Is there any reason this might be happening?

Comment: We cannot help you with seeing your code. Can you post the relevant portions of your Java and XML files?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try cleaning your project or post some code.

Sometimes the ID's do not get correctly regenerated if you are using Eclipse. This requires the project to be cleaned and sometimes refreshed.

Comment: That was all it was... What the hell happens to the project that requires a clean?

Comment: Eclipse gets buggered up quite often when building.

Comment: Although I am commenting too late, but I am facing this issue from a couple of days too. I am using Android Studio. I cleaned up my code, invalidate and restart, turn off the machine and restart, but the problem still persists. :( Please help as I am badly stuck.

Answer (score 285):

Make sure that you aren't really just trying to set the text to a number and expecting it to automatically convert to a string.

Comment: This solved my problem, too. I'm kind of surprised that they don't have a method that just wraps Integer.toString(), but whatever.

Comment: This is exactly in my case when I try to set text a number into a TextView which is pointed by a reference address generated by Eclipse. If you do so too, then you'll end up changing the target `TextView` reference address thus generating those error. So you MUST make sure that you don't put a number (or integer) into TextView's `setText()` method.

Comment: Same problem here. I solved putting String.valueof(myInt) inside the setText method

Comment: @androider I used to use `myTextView.setText(myInt + "");` myself. But according to [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653990/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-int-to-a-string) it looks like `myTextView.setText(Integer.toString(myInt));` is the most efficient way.

Comment: I had the same case in **Android Studio** and it solved! I wonder the reason by the way.

Comment: My case was just the opposite, I was trying to assign an Integer into a TextView. Thanks a lot for saving my day. :)

Comment: Yes something like `textView.setText(String.valueOf(line.getNumber()))`

Answer (score 26):

Exception Message thrown is not very descriptive. Its very much likely the case you are trying to cast the **int** value to **String**, applying the below change fixed the issue for me.

Code before the fix:

```
 itemPrice.setText(foodMenuItems.get(position).getItemPrice());
```

Code after the fix:

```
 itemPrice.setText(Integer.toString(foodMenuItems.get(position).getItemPrice()));
```

Comment: or just add "" before your int

Comment: worked for me! They should have implemented it to throw class cast exception or whatever, this is totally misleading

Comment: same for Toast messages, when you want to show int that you get from your pojo in a toast message Android Studio doesn't warn you

Answer (score 18):

Just to clarify Terra Caines answer since I saw it happening a lot to people;
`TextView`, and other text components, have 2 `setText()` functions with 1 parameter.

One of them is with a `String` and one with int. The `int` is obviously for a string Resource such as `R.string.myString` - which, to those who didnt know, `R.exm` always is represented as `int`. The string is for putting a string there.

So for example I want to put int `x = 1;` in a textView. Doing `mTextView.setText(x);`
will cause the textView to use the resource function and since there is probably no resource with the id 1 it will throw the exception Resource not found.
If You want to put an int or any number in the setText() Function make sure to convert it to `String` `(x+"")` or `(x.toString())` would do the trick for you.

Hope it saved some time to people.

Comment: Oh Man nice observation really saved my day :)

Answer (score 10):

`textViewCount.setText(someArray.size());` was my problem.

Simply call `toString();` to fix the problem.

```
    Integer size = mSomeArray.size();
    textViewReplyCount.setText(size.toString());
```

Comment: the problem was solved by adding `resultSizeOnUI.setText(((Integer)productSearchResultSize).toString());`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't set any attributes programmaticly which are not available.
I had the very same problem and the reason was a `RemoteView.setFloat(id,"setWeight",1.0f);` to a `LinearLayout`, which was not supported with Android before 4.x
Unfortunately the error message was not very helpful on this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had `int` variable (*on top of my Activity class*) and I was trying to pass that int variable as second parameter to `Toast.makeText()` (*to show that to the user*), I don't know I was stupid or android dev platform is! :p

Answer (score 0):

Check if the property `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` exists under the application tag of your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, I was trying to pass drawable selector with item android:color to background of view. The problem here is that you cannot define the background color using a color selector, you need a drawable selector.

Answer (score 0):

In my case
In the res/menu/(xml file)
In that xml file, in the 
there I used a png icon which was causing error
you should only use vector icon. This error was showing in android 6(marshmallow) and not in higher versions.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

declared twice in any of the resource files.

I had two of them in a file, removed one, and it worked like a charm.