# Getting android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: exception even when the resource is present in android

Tags: android, exception, layout, resources, landscape

Please let me know where I am going wrong to get the error.

I am creating an app which have one of its activity to be only in landscape mode. So I added the following in *AndroidManifest.xml* file

```
<activity android:name=".LandScapeImageActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

I have created a folder like

> /res/layout-land

and add a layout called see_today_landscape_layout in it.

and in `onCreate()` I added the following

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.see_today_landscape_layout);
....
}
```

But when I run my app I am getting the following error

```
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mid.kew.activities/com.mid.kew.activities.LandScapeImageActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03002b
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4066)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03002b
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1654)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at com.mid.kew.activities.LandScapeImageActivity.onCreate(LandScapeImageActivity.java:103)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
02-06 13:46:14.358: E/AndroidRuntime(13286):    ... 12 more
```

I crossed checked in *R.java* and it has the resource with the ID 7f03002b which the exception is looking for and it is present in there...

I cleaned and rebuild the project for say 5 times, but still the issue occurs.

Strange point is that this was working yesterday and it's not working today. The code is the same.

Comment: What does Resource ID #0x7f03002b refer to? You should provide the content of `see_today_landscape_layout.xml` file.

Comment: yes its refering to see_today_landscape_layout.xml as per R.java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android resource not found exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727808/android-resource-not-found-exception)

Comment: I had this issue when upgrading to use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` if I stay with `v7:22.2.0'` it works

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. in eclipse, go to Project > Clean...
2. select your project, then press OK
3. relaunch the app

if it happens again delete the r.java file. it will generate automatically.

Comment: as I mentioned before... I did clear bin and gen folders and rebuild the app.. still not working...

Comment: If this didn't fix your problem, why did it get the check mark?

Comment: what do you do if this happens on the release app?

Comment: It worked for me in Intellij. I was getting this exception for only release builds, but after Build -> Clean Project -> Restart IDE, my release build started to run as it should.

Answer (score 239):

For my condition the cause was taking `int` parameter for `TextView`. Let me show an example

```
int i = 5;
myTextView.setText(i);
```

gets the error info above.

This can be fixed by converting `int` to `String` like this

```
myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

As you write `int`, it expects a resource not the text that you are writing. So be careful on setting an `int` as a `String` in Android.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I was trying to do like this: num2.setText(lotteryCharacters.charAt(2));, then I changed to num2.setText(String.valueOf(lotteryCharacters.charAt(2)));...and it worked!

Comment: I wonder what's the difference between valueOf(i) and "" + i?

Comment: How about XAML code, how can I set the value. My case is should set decimal value for property on XAML

Comment: Thanks, the reason is that setText is overloaded method that accepts both String and resource Id. Then you pass an int it looks for resource Id

Comment: I had the same error with setting a char as a text to textview. This fixed it.

Answer (score 14):

Since you are setting the layout explicitly you might want to try and put it in the default /layout folder not in the /layout-land since that is if you want Android to automatically handle rotation for you.

Comment: If the phone is in portrait view it will be in portrait, when you rotate the phone it will be in landscape. Are you trying to make it always landscape? Then what you need to do is set the orientation of the activity to landscape in the Manifest file or in code see this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode

Comment: I have done that as I have mentioned in my question '<activity android:name=".LandScapeImageActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>'

Comment: you are missing the configchanges part <activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  android:name="abcActivty"/>

Answer (score 12):

Try moving your layout xml from `res/layout-land` to `res/layout` folder

Comment: *to* the layout folder?

Comment: from res/layout-land >> res/layout folder

Comment: Happened to me also, multiple times

Comment: I moved my xml from `res/layout-sw600dp` to `res/layout` then it's worked.. Thank you for your ans..

Answer (score 5):

I just get this error on Android 6.
I moved all drawables from drawable-v24 to drawable folder and the error is finally gone.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure that your imports are correct. I had a similar problem where `R` was pointing to the Android system `R` file, not my local one.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen due to a different language in the phone for which your code doesn't have the asset for. For example your preference.xml is placed in xml-en and you are trying to run your app in a phone which has French selected, the app will crash.

Comment: Always create default asset folders and then add language or orientation specific ones. Although this might or might not be the case over here :)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error from yet another reason:

I had the file `res/xml/data.xml` and I was trying to load it with `Resources` class like this:

```
Resources.getSystem().getXml(R.xml.data);
```

However this is incorrect as the method `Resources.getSystem()` returns a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources.

The correct way is as follows (from inside Activity):

```
this.getResources().getXml(R.xml.data);
```

Comment: How to access resources from top-level functions or classes that don't inherit from Activity then?

Answer (score 2):

In my case my Build Tools version in my build.gradle for the app module was outdated on an old project. Updating it fixed the issue:

```
android {
    ...
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"
    ...
```

Updated to the latest build tools version (25.0.1) and sync'd the project and all was well again.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted folders `build` inside a project. After cleaned and rebuilt it in Android Studio. Then corrected errors in build.gradle and AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 1):

This can also cause some trouble:
Accidentally one of my layouts was parked in my tablet resources folder, so I got this error only with phone layout. The phone layout simply had no suitable layout file.

**I worked again after moving the layout file in the correct standard folder and a following project rebuild.**

Comment: Could you provide more information on this please http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the R you are pointing to is the correct one. I had a problem very similar to this, where an import got inserted by Eclipse that pointed to the System R file rather than the project one. It took a lot of head scratching. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have screen orientation set to landscape in your xml. If you have used eclipse to generate this file it would have created under res/layout-land/ folder.But when you open activity in Portrait mode application will search for xml in res/layout-port/ folder or the regular res/layout/.
If you didn't have xml for portrait mode your application will crash.

Answer (score 0):

**I have fixed the by this way:**

Create a folder in your resource directory name `"drawable-nodpi"` and then move yours all resources in this directory from others drawable directory.

Now clean your project and then rebuilt. Run again hopefully it will work this time without any resource not found exception.

Comment: This pointed me to the right track but please keep in mind this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682094/will-a-density-qualified-drawable-folder-or-drawable-nodpi-take-precedence

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was trying to access Bundle data from One Intent by using getInt("ID").

I solved it by using getString("ID").

**From Activity1 i had**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("data",data)// 
startActivity(intent);
```

**On Activity B,**

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null){
// int x=extras.getInt("Data"); This Line gave me error int 
x=Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("Data")); // This solved the problem.
}
```

Comment: Please update your answer to explain how this solves the problem, and improves on the upvoted and accepted answers this 5-year old question already has.  See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please consider adding some details and explanation to support your answer so it is helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

For me cache invalidation and restart didn't work. I removed the .idea and .gradle folders. If you do that, don't forget that things like build logs or something might go away though.