# Resources$NotFoundException in built-in Android resource?

Tags: android, exception, layout, resources

I started a Android project on eclipse and make a simple loading bar, as follow:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LOG = true;

    // Initialize a GUI
    if(LOG) Log.d(TAG, "starting  content view and progress bar notifications");

    //initialize resource 
    // i put try to check the Exception
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.load);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loading_layout);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) rl.findViewById(R.id.progressBarLoad);
        mProgressText = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.textProgressLoad);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(LOG) Log.d(TAG, "bar notifications initialized");
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if(LOG){
                    Log.d(TAG, "starting update "+mProgress.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, "starting update "+mProgressText.toString());
                }

                while (mProgressStatus<100) {
                    //Do all process here
                    /*
                    if(mProgress % getNumberSubProcess() == 0){

                    }
                    */
                    LoadFEIAppActivity.this.update();
                    mProgressStatus += 0.01d; 
                }

                if(mProgressStatus==100){
                    LoadFEIAppActivity.this.update();
                    if(LOG) Log.d(TAG, "DONE");
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

    t.start();

    /*
    if(mProgressStatus==100){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterEmail.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
     */     
}
```

But the Application not runs as expected And i receive many Exceptions:

```
**03-21 16:25:51.977: W/System.err(363): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-21 16:25:51.987: W/System.err(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
03-21 16:25:51.997: W/System.err(363):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-21 16:25:51.997: W/System.err(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
03-21 16:25:51.997: W/System.err(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
03-21 16:25:52.007: W/System.err(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
03-21 16:25:52.017: W/System.err(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-21 16:25:52.017: W/System.err(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-21 16:25:52.017: W/System.err(363):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
03-21 16:25:52.028: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
03-21 16:25:52.028: W/System.err(363):  at unicamp.ia.feia.LoadFEIAppActivity.onCreate(LoadFEIAppActivity.java:45)
03-21 16:25:52.037: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-21 16:25:52.047: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
03-21 16:25:52.047: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-21 16:25:52.057: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-21 16:25:52.067: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-21 16:25:52.077: W/System.err(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 16:25:52.087: W/System.err(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-21 16:25:52.087: W/System.err(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-21 16:25:52.097: W/System.err(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 16:25:52.118: W/System.err(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-21 16:25:52.127: W/System.err(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-21 16:25:52.127: W/System.err(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-21 16:25:52.137: W/System.err(363):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 16:25:52.137: W/System.err(363): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-21 16:25:52.177: W/System.err(363):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:320)
03-21 16:25:52.177: W/System.err(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-21 16:25:52.189: W/System.err(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
03-21 16:25:52.197: W/System.err(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
03-21 16:25:52.207: W/System.err(363):  ... 22 more
03-21 16:25:52.207: W/System.err(363): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml from color state list resource ID #0x1030008
03-21 16:25:52.237: W/System.err(363):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1813)
03-21 16:25:52.247: W/System.err(363):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:289)
03-21 16:25:52.258: W/System.err(363):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:627)
03-21 16:25:52.267: W/System.err(363):  ... 26 more
03-21 16:25:52.277: W/System.err(363): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml from xml type colorstatelist resource ID #0x1030008
03-21 16:25:52.297: W/System.err(363):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1912)
03-21 16:25:52.307: W/System.err(363):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1808)
03-21 16:25:52.317: W/System.err(363):  ... 28 more
03-21 16:25:52.317: W/System.err(363): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml
03-21 16:25:52.357: W/System.err(363):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
03-21 16:25:52.367: W/System.err(363):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:469)
03-21 16:25:52.377: W/System.err(363):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1894)
03-21 16:25:52.377: W/System.err(363):  ... 29 more**
```

Researching on stackoverflow, i found some similar questions, but none with pleny solution:

- Clean and rebuild projects (not works)
- Check all resources (all there in res/), i.e, values/ strings/ layout/
- I Check xdpi folders, they not have same density (I have one version for each photos): see [Resources NotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468482/resources-notfoundexception)

I think in two problems:

- The density of photos affect the compilation process?
- or eclipse is missing a necessary built in resources?I'm considering it because of this message `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: hi gcrav post your progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml file...

Comment: The problem is this:  I did not create this file :P

Comment: There is no need to put "resolved" in your title. You've accepted an answer, that's enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check first you have `res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml` ? then

`progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml` in this xml you have not some state of of your `progressbar` so its problem,

**see this link** http://quickandroidblog.blogspot.in/2011/08/change-android-horizontal-progress-bar.html

Comment: Hi Jorgesys and Samir, the problem with this is that I didn´t create the `res/drawable/progress_iderteminate_horizontal.xml`. I think this is a built-in resource of Android SDK (?)

Comment: this problem has not appeared before, appeared only when I created another activity. I'll post the files in question layout and Manifest

Comment: Sorry samir, I mistook what you meant (this intermediate English ... :P), i will try and post again

Comment: Ok @Samir, reading all posts, and 'hacking' android, i make this: in file `res/layout/loading.xml`, that´s the file with problem, i add a simple line with: `android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"/>` and the specific Exception (`InflateException`) dissapears. I have now other Exception: `E/AndroidRuntime(295): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application unicamp.ia.feia.fEIApp2012: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: unicamp.ia.feia.fEIApp2012 in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e8cdd0`

Comment: ops, I add the line in element <ProgressBar></Progressbar> ;)

Comment: add your full logcat in your question

Comment: The RuntimeException is my mistake, i change one line in manifest, but the problem that I posted is resolved. Thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

the .xml file

> res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml

has references of colors that doesn't exist in your proyect!

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml from color state list resource ID #0x1030008

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml from xml type colorstatelist resource ID #0x1030008
```

yes, the density of photos will affect but since you are using res/drawable/ that is the default folder and you have the resources in your proyect it doesn´t affect the compilation

post your res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml

Answer (score 0):

As follow, manifest.xml and the layout used in the Activity with problem:

The hierarchy tree in my Project is (in relation with xml files):

- res/

  - layout/

    - loading.xml
    - registeremail.xml
  - drawable/

    - hdpi/

      - logo.png
      - mulherfeia2012.jpg
    - mdpi/

      - nothing
    - ldpi/

      - nothing

The `res/layout/loading.xml`, with i tried to run

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarLoad"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textProgressLoad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBarLoad"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/loading_message"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageLoad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBarLoad"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_feia_description"
        android:src="@drawable/mulherfeia2012" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="unicamp.ia.feia"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.1" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7" android:maxSdkVersion="7"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/feia12_logo_low"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:testOnly="false" 
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoadFEIAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".RegisterEmail">
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Thank very much for help!

Comment: remembering: i didn´t create in any moment the file `res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml`