# Set an item long click listener in GridView

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I want to add an item long click listener, which will set the image selected as wallpaper. I am getting images from web and displaying them in a grid view. My grid activity is shown below. I already have an on click listener to show a full screen image.

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends BaseActivity {

String[] imageUrls;

DisplayImageOptions options;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_grid);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
            .cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc()
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());

    // Set Long-Clickable
    gridView.setLongClickable(true);
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageAdapter i = (ImageAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    (int) i.getItemId(position));

            // Get the WallpaperManager
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                    .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            try {
                // Set the clicked bitmap
                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(mBitmap);
                Toast.makeText(ImageGridActivity.this, "Wallpaper set",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(ImageGridActivity.this, "Error setting wallpaper",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            startImageGalleryActivity(position);
        }
    });

    gridView.setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(true, true));

}

private void startImageGalleryActivity(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
    intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, position);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

> logcat

```
     01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x2
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1105)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:554)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:630)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.ImageGridActivity$1.onItemLongClick(ImageGridActivity.java:67)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2622)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2572)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-22 16:00:35.101: E/AndroidRuntime(29785):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> android manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader"
    android:versionCode="26"
    android:versionName="1.7.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

    <application
        android:name=".UILApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:allowBackup="True"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ImageGridActivity"
            android:label="@string/ac_name_image_grid" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ImagePagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/ac_name_image_pager" />


        <!-- Widget -->
        <receiver android:name=".widget.UILWidgetProvider">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: look at log cat its saying Resources$NotFoundException check you had added resources correctly

Comment: did you provide permission to set wall paper??

Comment: yes i have added the permission too

Comment: is this the log cat when you done long press to set wall paper??

Comment: i am getting images from the web using the universal image loader

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `OnItemLong listener` instead `OnItemClick Listener`.

Instead of:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            startImageGalleryActivity(position);
        }
    });
```

Use

```
 gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
       startImageGalleryActivity(position);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Updated**

*OnItemClickListener*

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
                  Toast.makeText(test2.this, "Click Listener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                   // open the pager activity
                  }    });
```

*OnItemLongClickListener*

```
gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int position, long arg3) {
                        Toast.makeText(test2.this, "LONG PRESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //set the image as wallpaper 
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: i want both item click listner which will open the pager activity..and also the onItemLongClickListner which will set the image as wallpaper

Comment: thanks but plz check the code i wrote for set image as wallpaper in long click listener...the app still crashes on long click

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead :

```
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Write This part in your code to set long Click on gridview

```
    GridView  gridView =  (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    //Set Long-Clickable
    gridView.setLongClickable(true);
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position , long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            /*
                             *You Can use parameters like position,view or id to
                             *Customize your action
                             */   
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Click Listener

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

To Set Wall Paper i think it need to set permission

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
```

**Note :** look at log cat its saying `Resources$NotFoundException` check you had added resources correctly. may be on wrong folder or something check  [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468672/1450401)

Comment: i want both item click listner which will open the pager activity..and also the onItemLongClickListner which will set the image as wallpaper...it does not perform long click method...but only the on click method

Comment: yes i got it :)
can u help in setting the wallpaper..see the code in long click listener...the app crashes on long click

Comment: i am getting images from the web using the universal image loader

Answer (score 1):

First of all,change this line.

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnItemLongClickListener
```

Then add this code in your activity ...

```
 GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
 gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,long id) 
    {
        System.out.println("~~~~~~Long Item Clicked");
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: the app crashes on long click now...i want to set selected item as wallpaper...has to be because og this line...but how to overcome this                            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    (int) i.getItemId(position));

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Return true in onItemLongClick and your onItemClickListener is not called :)

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
.
.
.
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
gridView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            });
```