# Resource Not found in actionbar

Tags: android, view, actionbarsherlock, android-resources

I have a case where my app crashes after a day or two giving ResourceNotFoundException at the below line.But it doesn't crash when i run now or after few minutes.only after a day is passed im getting this exception

```
oItem.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress); In oncreateoptionsMenu function
```

below is my crash log

```
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030018
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:565)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at com.qz.XXX.XXXX.onCreateOptionsMenu(xxxx.java:202)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:45)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:559)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:479)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:272)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat$1.run(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:984)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-04 12:00:18.367: E/AndroidRuntime(15535):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: next time it crashes, please add your crash log

Comment: have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9468672/1056359)?

Comment: yeah..But i have setting an layout for the SetActionView not from drawable

Comment: Can you post the code your `actionbar_indeterminate_progress` layout ?

Comment: Sorry !!! i had made a mistake of adding a xml to layout-v11 and was checking in device with android < 11 ...

Comment: So your problem resolved now right ? If yes then post your answer.