# Change color to default of non-selected item in ListView

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android

I want to change the color of `TextView` in `ListView` to the themes default, but right now it has different "non-selected" color ( gray in my case instead of white ). I have tried following code, to pick theme default color, but it gives me an error `Binary XML file...`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/botText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColor"
/>
```

Comment: replace 
?android:attr/textColor
with 
@android:attr/textColor

if you want to use the color of your own selection then use Selector

Comment: @UsmanKurd I still get the same error. `error inflating class <unknown>`

Comment: 1st debug the code with Break point where you think it can cause crash and back track from that
and still could not find any sol then paste code and log cat error here

Comment: @UsmanKurd `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path)`

Comment: put Your code here and Also Review this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161435/getting-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-exception-even-when-the

Comment: @UsmanKurd which part of the code? my XML is above.

Comment: are you getting error on saving the XML file ? or on Running the Application ? 
if you are getting this on rrunning application then place your .Java file code