# Android Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030027

Tags: android, android-resources

I was working on my android program and when I tried testing it I suddenly started getting an error that went "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030027" The last major change I made was adding in the action bar via the support library but I got that working fine already. Besides that I've added one new class but even if I delete the class and it's associated files the error still pops up. I have tried cleaning the project and restarting Eclipse multiple times to no avail.

Here's the stack trace in case anything got lost in translation:

```
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blackhat.htmlparsingtest/com.blackhat.htmlparsingtest.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030027
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030027
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1026)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2131)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:865)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1914)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:111)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at com.blackhat.htmlparsingtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
01-21 19:05:53.125: E/AndroidRuntime(18599):    ... 11 more
```

Also I have checked the R.java file and the resource definitely exists, though as I mentioned cleaning the project, deleting the R file and restarting Eclipse does nothing. One thing I felt should be mentioned however is that I've found two R.java files, one is in my project folder along with BuildConfig.Java. The other one is in android.support.v7.appcompat. I know appcompat can cause some problems so I thought it was worth mentioning in just in case.

I can't even get my code working how it used to, so any help would be appreciated and let me know if you need any other information!

Comment: I would say clean project but seeing as you've already done that, we're going to need some code to help you out.

Comment: If you have android.R in your imports, remove it and try again, but apart from that, as @Clay said, we will need more info.

Comment: Ok, what kind of code exactly? I would assume you need code from my MainActivity and maybe the stack trace?

Comment: You can try alternative provided in ans of this que.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can check your R file for `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030027`. It'll tell you which resource was creating the problem. As an alternative solution I think you might have `setText` or any content just an `int`.And as you know here compiler will look for corresponding resource value. So, just concat an empty string there as `""`

Comment: That actually helped! As it turned out, somehow at some point the xml file got deleted from the layout folder... I appreciate the help!

Comment: `You might have set text or any content just an int` Yes...That's the mistake I was doing..Thank you @Manmohan

Comment: "You might have set text or any content just an int", yes it happened to me, once I put "String.valueOf(myInteger)" then everything is OK. Thanks.

Comment: This helped me find the "problematic" resource however it is defined in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi. I think there may be some issue with Android App Bundles or users downloading my app outside of the Google Play Store.  I am really not sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: @toobsco42, are you using .aab too? I got this kind of error in my aab logs

Answer (score 27):

I was getting this exception:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02004f

I was calling `PNG Icon` from 
**...\app\src\main\res\drawable-21**

When I put my `PNG Icon` into
**...\app\src\main\res\drawable** and I call it,
My problem goes away

BTW `XML` worked from `\drawable-21`

Answer (score 12):

I had this same issue too:

As I was trying to move some files into another directory within the IDE, somehow I made a mistake by moving a layout xml file from the **layout** directory into the **layout-land** directory.

It worked after I moved it back.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This answer saved me! 
At first I didn't understand what the answer meant, so for anyone who needs instructions:
View->Tool Windows ->Project
And then check on which folder the layout is at.

Answer (score 8):

I tried to move image files **(png,jpg)** from **drawable-v24** to **drawable**

It solved the Problem

Comment: i had same issue, this answer worked, strange how android studio can't detect file stored in drawable-v24. moving files to drawable folder worked

Comment: It might be something with emulator screen densities

Answer (score 7):

In my case error occured after update to Android Studio build: 3.0 Canary 6, i fixed it in downgradeing it to the previous version 3.0 Canary-5 and build tools canary-5.

The issue was related with some incompability with vector drawables on api 19 and below

EDIT:
It's looks like that mentioned issue was resolved on ***Android Studio build: 3.0 Canary 7***

Comment: How can I downgrade my android studio?

Answer (score 4):

For me, while creating layout file it landed in `layout-land` folder, hence the exception. 
Hope it will help someone.

Comment: That's what my problem is. Thanks :)

Comment: That was it. Android Studio gets wild sometimes when pasting layouts between projects.

Answer (score 3):

I have just come across the same issue- cleaning and rebuilding the project solved the problem for me!

Comment: I restarted Visual studio, deleted bin and obj folder. Cleaned and rebuild the project and finally the issue got resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

a) there could be an error in any of your resource xml files (strings, layouts, anim,etc..) and your.package.name.R cannot compile with that error

EX:

```
<string name="main_header">My problem wasn't in java it was in this string</string>
```

**Error:** apostrophe`'` needs to be preceeded by a backslash `\`

**Correction:**

```
<string name="main_header">My problem wasn\'t in java it was in this string</string>
```

or,

b) You imported the wrong "R" into your class. make sure you import `your.package.name.R` and not `android.R`

EX:

```
//You DO NOT want this, unless you are working directly with android's 
  resources, not your own in your project
import android.R
```

**Correction:**

```
// You want to reference your project's resources, not Android OS's
import your_package_name_here.R
```

Hope this helps, Happy Coding!

Comment: Now that you mention it, when creating the new class I originally had it not modify strings.xml, nor create a menu or layout (since I planned to use a different menu and layout file anyway. Could this cause situation A?

Comment: No that shouldn't affect it, and if it did, I'm sure it wouldn't do it with errors. See my updated answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Checked my code after your edit, and I noticed that R isn't imported at all. I don't recall ever importing it either, though I could be wrong. I don't know if that makes a difference but if so then I have no idea how the import got removed from all of my classes without me directly editing them. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: If you are not importing R (no `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)`) then I beleive your error lies in xml somewhere. I may be wrong but that's all I can think of. run android lint, it may help you out

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error on on Android 4.2.2 but not on Android 5 and Android 6.
Reason was I had put some vector icons (xml files for navigation drawer) in drawable-v21 folder because by default android generated navigation drawer icons e.g. ic_menu_gallery.xml were residing in drawable-v21 folder. Moving these xml files (which i generated and not default ones) to drawable folder solved my problem. Don't move default generated icons to drawable else it might cause duplicate exception.

Answer (score 1):

You could be calling a string from project resources with

`Resources().getSystem().getString(
  R.string.my_string_id)`

which refers to global resources. To refer to your project resources do getString() directly from your activity:

```
this.getString(
  R.string.my_string_id); // From within your activity class.

myActivity.getString(
  R.string.my_string_id); // From other classes as instance reference.
```

Answer (score 1):

*First step :* 
ctrl + maj + f : look for the code of the issue here = `#0x7f030027`

*2nd step*
Read the name of the value, find where it is used.

*3rd step*
If it is a PNG maybe you have not put all different sizes of it. 
[image: /Users/churlet/Desktop/Capture d’écran 2018-08-06 à 10.31.06.png]

Answer (score 1):

[image: drawable folder image]

replace image icon from drawable-v24 to drawable, that solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link , maybe it will help you , it is the same problem. If the cleaning of project does not help you try to delete your r.java file it will be generated itself.
[Getting android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: exception even when the resource is present in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161435/getting-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-exception-even-when-the)

Comment: Nope, I tried deleting R.Java as it recommended, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I am getting this error only on Galaxy S5 not with a Motorola phone. Why is this?

Comment: @The_Martian This is most likely because your issue is due to different phone densities. Check that any file you a referencing is in all of the stalks for both devices as maybe it can't find a file on on device.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vector drawable in the resource.xml which has a `<layer-list>` on API version 19 or lower you will get this exception

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a custom style for my vertical scrollbar in scroll view like this:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
  ..>
```

and my style was like:

```
 <style name="scrollbar_shape_style">
  ...
```

I changed the first part to this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:theme="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
```

and added parent to the style like this:

```
<style name="scrollbar_shape_style" parent="LightTheme">
```

and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the ResourceException problem when I first use BottomNavigationDrawer widget. Tyr to add all resourses for all possible dimensions, in the end, I got rid of the problem by removing all drawable-v21, and drawable-v24 folders, just leaving the conventional drawable folders.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing this issue using a custom UI library, so app:srcCompt was not available. I was using latest gradle build(v3.4.1) and after downgrading to v3.2.1 the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was setting an integer value to the `TextView.setText()`. Because it was an int, it was assuming that it's a resource id which of course wasn't the case.

```
year = 1947;
textView.setText(year) ------>>>> Error!
```

Fixed it by converting the integer value to string-

```
textView.setText(year + "");

or

textView.setText(String.valueOf(year));
```

Answer (score -1):

Your probably developing for newer android version from your current device.
Try download SDK that is appropriate to your testing device.

Answer (score -2):

You might used same resource photo twice.
 this happened with me when used photo twice:
**first** time in main screen **then** used the same photo in another activity.