# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a003b type #0x5 is not valid

Tags: android, linphone

I am trying to use the Linphone library for Android. I have installed all the libraries as specified and when I am trying to run the project, I am getting the below error.

```
  Process: org.linphone, PID: 13440
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.linphone/org.linphone.LinphoneLauncherActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a003b type #0x5 is not valid
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0a003b type #0x5 is not valid
       at android.content.res.Resources.getBoolean(Resources.java:999)
       at org.linphone.LinphoneLauncherActivity.onCreate(LinphoneLauncherActivity.java:50)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Please let me know how can I resolve this as my work is stuck because of this.
Thanks in advance !!.

Comment: you also need to post the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this ans:
[Android Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030027](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269502/android-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x7f030027)

> You can check your R file for Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030027. It'll tell you which resource was creating problem. As an alternative sollution I think you might have setText or any content just an int.And as you know here compiler will look for corresponding resource value. So, just concat an empty string there as ""

Comment: I haven't set any integer value in edittext. I am using the Linphone library to make video calls. I have done the complete setup and now when I am trying to run it, it is giving me error.