# Android Studio: Error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080066

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am developing a small App and the minimum API-Level is set to 23 (Android 6). However the App is not running on this Level. On an Emulator running on API-Level 27 (Android 8.1) I runs perfectly fine (Also tested an actual Devices - same result. The Debugger only tells me this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.moehl.max.tableformatter, PID: 4958
                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080066
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
```

and so on see: https://pastebin.com/3Nkw6QAR

But I have no idea what the Problem could be. If needed I can paste more code.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?
Thanks

Edit: I checked which ressourcefile is causing the Problem in my R file, it is a file called ic_menu_file.xml (v24), it wasn't in the normal drawable folder but in the drawable-24 folder (I have no clue why) and also in my file tree it showed up in the normal drawable folder. I moved it and now everything works fine!
Also I don't know what to do with this post

Comment: Please include code and any configuration that may help in solving said issue.

Comment: post adapter class code along with question

Comment: I think you might set an int value to any `textview.setText(int_value)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030027](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269502/android-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x7f030027)