# Error when Running on Emulator SDK 22 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07006c

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f07006c
>
> ```
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1313)
>     at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:145)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
>     at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)
>     at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:125)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:210)
>     at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:187)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:196)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:476)
>     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1164)
>     at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:95)
>     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:229)
>     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:291)
>     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1051)
>     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1078)
>     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1419)
>     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1657)
>     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:134)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
> ```

when i run the apps on emulator SDK 27, it's fine. above is the error message when i run the application. on my Build.Gradle i use Sdk 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is issue related resources

1. It might happen if you are trying to setText int value instead of String
2. may your resource file in **drawable-21** folder and it looking into the **drawable** folder[Just put the resource into drawable folder]

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269502/android-resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-id-0x7f030027)