# Split APK missing when installing app from Play Store

Tags: android, apk

Recently we released our application on Play Store using Android Application Bundle.
Our app has a native library and of course some resources. When installing Play Store will put language specific resources and platform specific library in a separate split APKs.

There are some crashes reported with missing native library and/or missing resources. I don't see any common things among all these crashes and I can't reproduce it.

Is it possible that the app will be only partially installed due to some network or space issues? Why it's not detected by system installer and are there any ways to detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be various reasons for Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID, in case of app bundles :

1. Drawable resource is not present in correct directory, adding resource in default drawable directory or in all respective drawable directories like `ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi` may solve it: [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000212/905858)
2. Your app is side loaded i.e. instead of downloading the app from a legitimate app store, it is shared between users. In such a case the apk shared would have resources only specific to that device: [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53082301/905858)

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer on how to prevent sideloading