# Resource not found exception while screen rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I have a problem in application, when I have a `landscape` mode application for tablet and small devices. I have put all the layout files in `layout-land` and `layout-sw600dp-land` folder. I have defined screen `orientation` in `manifest` file also. When I explore application, keeping mobile `portrait` I found an error of `ResourceNotFoundException`. How can I solve this problem?. Hoping for favorable answer.

Following is my menifest file implementation

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ForgotPassword"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.LoginFragment"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.Lending"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SavedTakeOff"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ItemsFragment"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Comment: Do you have all the layouts in your layout folder for mobile screen?

Comment: post the whole stackstrace and directory structure,before that try cleaning and building

Comment: You must be missing some id in your xml....post your Log here

Comment: @Jas, It is compulsory to manage all layouts in "layout"  folder when we are developing for landscape mode only.

Comment: post where are you getting error

Comment: Is you app support both layout support portrai and landscape  ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161435/getting-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-exception-even-when-the

Comment: post your manifest please .

Comment: @HareshChhelana My app is only support landscape mode only.

Comment: Then remove '-land' from layout and given fix landscape orientation android:screenOrientation="landscape" in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I think this is suitable for your questions..
http://stackoverflow.com/q/9161435/5668375

Comment: @Bhumit I already gone through your link. But didn't get any result yet.

Answer (score 1):

if you are following multiple layout support it is not limited to just land and port mode which you already know. but in order to portrait mode you need to keep your file in default layout folder.

```
MyProject/
res/
    layout/              # default (portrait)
        main.xml
    layout-land/         # landscape
        main.xml
    layout-large/        # large (portrait)
        main.xml
    layout-large-land/   # large landscape
        main.xml
```

Comment: these qualifiers are deprecated

Comment: @VivekMishra I followed same structure for my landscape application as you posted above. But while exploring application sometime I face the issue of design change. It seems that sometime application bind layout from "layout" folder instead of "layout-land" folder.

Comment: I have not posted that . I am saying that now you should use sw<dp> notation to create folders for different resolutions layout. And double check your layouts and manifest  for orientation and layout

Answer (score 1):

This is because when your device is in portrait Mode and you try to open the application it by default try to load resources of portrait mode then later it will change the orientation to Landscape(based on your manifest configuration) So you can just add a default layout of launcher screen on portrait mode this will solve your resource not Found exception and application still be loaded in Landscape mode.

Comment: I put all landscape layout in default layout folder as per your suggestion. But while exploring application sometime I face the issue of design change. It seems that sometime application bind layout from "layout" folder instead of "layout-land" folder.

Comment: No, no need to put all the layouts in the default layout folder, Just add layout of Launcher in the Layout folder in your case .SplashScreenActivity. Even if this does not work add Configuration change listener and post details to help us debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your R.java. then clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple i you use this class.you call this class and check its mobile or tablet

```
public class Utils {
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
{
    final int buffer_size=1024;
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;)
        {
          int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
          if(count==-1)
              break;
          os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}

public static boolean isTablet(Activity activity) {
    return (activity.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
        & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
        >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}}
```

simply you call In Activity you call this its will check mobile or tablet

```
 if (!Utils.isTablet(this))
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```