# how to call array base api through gson library please tell me how to call this through gson

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RecyclerviewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


## this is my main activity here i add my data into recyclerview##

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        apiData();
    }


    public void apiData()
    {
        dialog.show();
        Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
//        param.put("TOKEN","b0dba610e269abc702843d1cf636b786");
//        Log.d("tokenvalue", String.valueOf(param));

        String url = "http://104.131.114.237/saathi/api/getAllHrOptions";

        APIManager.getInstance().callAPI(Request.Method.GET, url, param, this, new APIManager.APICallbackInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccessFinished(String result)
            {
                dialog.cancel();


                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();


                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

                List<DataProvider> dataProviders = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(result,DataProvider[].class));
                adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(dataProviders);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorFinished(String result) {

                dialog.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### This is my api format array based

Method: GET

Output:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Salary Slip",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "ESIC Related",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Attendance",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Service Charge",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Others",
            "status": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You mean to say `parse array base api`?

Comment: yes i want to pass data into recylerview

Comment: i am able to print  "code": 200,
    "message": "Success", this only but i am not able to to add data

Comment: AbhayBohra's answer will help you

Comment: And if you want to print code and message just use `model.getCode()` and `model. getMessage()` respectively (Reference from AbhayBohra's answer)

Comment: bro i want to print id name status in my recyclerview

Comment: So if you want to print id, name and status in RecyclerView, AbhayBohra's will work. If not working then please post what error your are getting in your question itself.

Comment: there is no error but my data is not print in recycler view

Comment: Post your adapter code

Comment: List<DataProvider> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecyclerviewAdapter(List<DataProvider> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

Comment: public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView id,name,status;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tittle);
            status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

Comment: give me your mail id i will mail you the project please bro help me out its very urgent for me

Comment: You can post it in your question itself. Just click on Edit option

Comment: i am not able to do edit the post and please give me ur mail id i wi;; main u all project and after correct send me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DataProvider model = gson.fromJson(result, DataProvider.class);
dataProviders.addAll(model.getData());
```

and your model class should look like this

```
public class DataProvider {

    private int code;
    private String message;
    private List<DataBean> data;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<DataBean> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataBean> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static class DataBean {

        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String status;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where i pass the api array name (data) in my main activity

Comment: Check my Edit..It will automatically detect..only you have to make the model class like this...try it

Comment: DataProvider model = gson.fromJson(result, DataProvider.class);
dataProviders.addAll(model.getData());           // i have problem in this code can you please elaborate

Comment: What problem are you getting?

Comment: when i launch my app it give error   in this method      @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


        holder.id.setText(list.get(position).getCode());
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getMessage());
    }

Comment: adapter code is too long it will not add in comment

Comment: Process: in.advaitsolutions.www.gsondemo, PID: 29082
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xc8
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:353)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4590)
        at in.advaitsolutions.www.gsondemo.RecyclerviewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerviewAdapter.java:35)

Comment: public class RecyclerviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    List<DataProvider> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecyclerviewAdapter(List<DataProvider> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

Comment: @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

Comment: @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


        holder.id.setText(list.get(position).getCode());
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getMessage());
        holder.status.setText((CharSequence) list.get(position).getData());
    }

Comment: @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView id,name,status;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tittle);
            status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        }
    }
}

Comment: In you onBindViewHolder in setText, add +""

for ex  holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getMessage()+"");
in all textViews

Comment: For more details about resourceNot Found exception..check this

https://stackoverflow.com/q/9161435/3789993

Comment: "code": 200,
    "message": "Success",  only this print in my application not hole data

Comment: my application run successfully but it not print the hole data                 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();


                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

                //List<DataProvider> dataProviders = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(result,DataProvider[].class));
                List<DataProvider> model = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(result, DataProvider.class));
                adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(model);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: can you please tell me how to print all data please sir its working but partially

Comment: hye bro where are u please help me bro