# Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-activity, android-inflate

PLease any good android developer help me resolve this issue

issue happening here :

```
android:background="@drawable/splash_bg"
```

**splash_bg** is vector image

and my **sdk target is 28** 
if i remove this  **(android:background="@drawable/splash_bg")** then code pass by this and then any other activity have background defined and it gives error:

I tried:

1) check all xml images are in drawable not in *-v24

2) size of splash_bg

but nothing seems work resolve this issue

PLEASE PLEASE Help me to resolve this issue, I will very thankfull.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:background="@drawable/splash_bg"

    android:id="@+id/vSplash"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<!--        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivbelowLogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_zayed_big" />-->

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivSplash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivSplashGif"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_loading"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/versionLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvVersion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="@string/version_name"/>

        <!--<TextView android:id="@+id/tvPowered"-->
            <!--android:layout_below="@id/tvVersion"-->
            <!--android:textSize="12dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_centerVertical="true"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:text="@string/beta_version" />-->

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Working fine on all devices except few it is crashing.

This is the issue:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ae.abc.xyzapp/ae.abc.xyzapp.ui.InitActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at ae.mazadat.onlineauctionapp.ui.InitActivity.onCreate(InitActivity.java:87) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080216
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at ae.mazadat.onlineauctionapp.ui.InitActivity.onCreate(InitActivity.java:87) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554) 
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464) 
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at ae.mazadat.onlineauctionapp.ui.InitActivity.onCreate(InitActivity.java:87) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your .xml code.

Comment: You're getting a "Resources not found" exception. It might be worth checking this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161435/getting-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-exception-even-when-the

Comment: it is crashing on samsung and selected mobile but need to fix .... it will be really helpfull if you can help. Thank you

Comment: Amit Tiwary ? or anyone help plz

Answer (score 0):

That will only work if the device is running Android >= 5.X.X. Support for vector drawables was introduced there.

There are some compatibility options for ImageView on the AndroidX library, but I am not sure you can do anything for the background attribute on layouts. Just add a .png in your drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, etc, etc, to support API levels below 21.

Comment: check this:
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 90
        versionName "4.1.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

Comment: check the buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'  and targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: Your targetSdkVersion doesn't matter, I'm talking about the Android version your phone/tablet is running.

Comment: i am using geny motion to check on note 3

Comment: tell me just one thing like if i add splash_bg png in all drawable folder so it will work fine right?

Comment: Check first for the Android version that device is running. And yes, I think your problem could be solved that way.

Comment: i dont want prople download application who donot support SVG  ?? should i follow it ?

Comment: can i have solution like it support both SVG and PNG ?

Comment: @Reaper What is the source of that information? About supporting SVG? I found official doc, where it's possible to use SVG with old Android. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg

Comment: Yes if i add the svg in asset folder then it will work? GenasGAmes am i right bro?>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you have added your `SVG` resources with Android import, as described [in the official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this situation by an other way. It seems to be good for somehow.

Add an `ImageView`  in your `RelativeLayout` and put your **splash_bg** img there in ImageView rather than RelativeLayout. By going this way your app will not crash and you will get the solution.

Update your XML like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_bg" <!--remove from here -->
    android:id="@+id/vSplash"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- put your splash here -->
    <ImageView  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_bg"/>


 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: can u tell me by doing it 

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_bg"/>

It will leave spaces from left and right?

How to resolve that cause i did and its leaving left and right spaces

Comment: @FaisalLiaquat - Probably, It depends on the image you're using. Use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` or `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your ImgView. It will fit your image to the whole screen if there will be any space in any axis.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

i marked it alreadt but one more quesiton

like on layout wise its working but what about when i try to do like R.drawable.menu_icons_my_account

Comment: but what about when i try to do like R.drawable.menu_icons_my_account it is not getting the image

Comment: @FaisalLiaquat - From which folder/directory you wanna get image?

Comment: R.drawable.new_logo 

when i am doing ivLogo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_logo));

it is crashing cause same issue new_logo cannot find ... i am runnning android version less than 5.0.0

Comment: Put the code like this `ivLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_logo);`

This may help!

Comment: @IrfanAkram Did you try my answer?

Comment: i want to try it @GensaGames but the problem is if its even worked then i dont have all the svgs properly. As all the files are in XML, if you hvae idea can u tell me if i can convert XML to SVG , no online tool used