# Icon exists in drawable folder but I get resource not found exception

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, svg, android-vectordrawable

I have my SVG icon in the drawable folder, but I keep getting the resource not found exception. Here's the full log message, I appreciate your help.

`Process: com.audioplayer.mp3player.sandy.app, PID: 15875
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.audioplayer.mp3player.sandy.app/com.audioplayer.mp3player.sandy.app.Activity.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #208: Binary XML file line #208: Error inflating class ImageButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #208: Binary XML file line #208: Error inflating class ImageButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_plus_library.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800fe
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4220)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4089)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3939)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)`

Comment: "I have my SVG icon in the drawable folder" -- do you literally mean an SVG file? If so, that is not a valid resource format. You can use the Vector Asset wizard in Android Studio to convert some SVG files to vector drawables, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have used the Vector Asset wizard to convert them into vector drawables for all of my icons in my project.   I get this error specific to 'ic_plus_library.xml' file.

Answer (score 0):

if answers given in [Android resource not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161435/getting-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-exception-even-when-the) did not worked for you, check your xml file with your vector code.

I experienced this error because I wanted to put a vector without a path, just to fill a raw, found out this was a bad idea...