# ResourcesNotFoundException on some devices

Tags: android, bitmap, crash

I recently received crash reports of my app. It says this:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi/bg.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020005
```

and then this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:601)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:576)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:439)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
```

I tested my app on several devices and none of them had crashed.
According to the users of my app, this error appears to be on a Samsung Galaxy y pro
I really don't know what to do...

Comment: Which of your folders have a bg.png?

Comment: Only drawable-xhdpi, should I put it into all drawable folders?

Comment: I've seen a similar crash report on an app. The device in question was also a Samsung Galaxy Y. I have not been able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I got the same problem. The reason is propably a rounding issue. My image is only 1 pixel high so the device propably scales it below 0.5px in height and ends up creating a bitmap with a height of 0px.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android resource not found exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727808/android-resource-not-found-exception)

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong. The Galaxy Y has little screen and so low resolution. And I think this device doesn't know what is xhdpi folder, so you should place your drawable into all folders...

Hope, it helps :)

Comment: At least you man place drawable for all other resources in drawable folder or drawable-nodpi. System should look into these folders when it can't find resource in needed.