# How to display data retrieved from the SOAP ListView?

Tags: android

Welcome
I have a problem with the addition of a ListView data retrieved from `SOAP`.
When you create a `ListView` pops the following error:

```
04-06 00:12:47.852: W / dalvikvm (4092): threadid = 1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group = 0x409c01f8) 
04-06 00:12:48.123: E /AndroidRuntime (4092): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
04-06 00:12:48.123: E /AndroidRuntime (4092): android.content.res.Resources $NotFoundException: Resource ID # 0x7f08000c type # 0x12 is not valid
```

Not understand what was happening.

Please help solve the problem and explain what is happening in the error gets called.

```
package com.example.pit_testy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.pit_testy.R;
import com.example.pit_testy.soap.AsyncTaskManager;
import com.example.pit_testy.soap.GetSoapTaskTest;
import com.example.pit_testy.soap.OnAsyncTaskCompleteListener;
import com.example.pit_testy.soap.PitTestyMsg;
import com.example.library.UserFunctions;

public class TestyActivity extends Activity {

    UserFunctions userFunctions;

    private Button buttonWynik, buttonStartTest;
    private CountDownTimer testTotalClock;
    private long initialTotalTime = 300000;
    private long intervalSecondTime = 1000;
    private AsyncTaskManager taskMenager;
    private TextView textClock, textQuestion;
    private ListView listQuestions;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListQuestions;
    private String categoryID = "0";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testy);

        taskMenager = new AsyncTaskManager(this);

        textClock = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
        textClock.setText("Czas start!");
        textQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTrescPytania);
        textQuestion.setText("Treść pytania");

        testTotalClock = new CountDownTimer(initialTotalTime, intervalSecondTime) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Integer milisec = new Integer(new Double(millisUntilFinished).intValue());
                Integer cdSecs = milisec / 1000;
                Integer minutes = (cdSecs % 3600) / 60;
                Integer seconds = (cdSecs % 3600) % 60;

                textClock.setText(minutes.toString()+":"+seconds.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textClock.setText("Koniec czasu!");

                userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent nextView = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WynikActivity.class);

                nextView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(nextView);

            }
        };  

        loadTest(categoryID); // wybór kategorji

        buttonStartTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStartTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                testTotalClock.start();             
                textQuestion.setText("Jak masz na imie?");
            }
        });     

        buttonWynik = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonWynik);
        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        buttonWynik.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                testTotalClock.cancel();

                userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent nextView = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WynikActivity.class);

                nextView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(nextView);
            }
        });

        testTotalClock.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.testy, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void loadTest(String category) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("aid", "1");
        map.put("categories", category);

        GetSoapTaskTest task = new GetSoapTaskTest();
        taskMenager.executeTask(task, GetSoapTaskTest.createRequest("getCategories", new JSONObject(map).toString()), "Wykonano executeTask", 
            new OnAsyncTaskCompleteListener<PitTestyMsg>() {

                ArrayList<String> arrayListQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();

                @Override
                public void onTaskCompleteSuccess(PitTestyMsg result) {
                    if (result.errorCode == 0){
                            for (Map <String, String> var : result.data) {
                            Log.i("SoapCategories", "Testy pobrane = " + var.get("name"));
                            arrayListQuestions.add(var.get("name"));

                        }

                        taskMenager.onPostExecute(arrayListQuestions);

                        Intent mainTest = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestyActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainTest);

                    }else{
                        Log.i("SoapCategories", "Testy niepobrane");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onTaskFailed(Exception cause) {
                    Log.e("Soap", cause.getMessage(), cause);

                }


        });
    }

}


public final class AsyncTaskManager implements IProgressTracker {

    private final ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private ListView listQuestions;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    private Context myContext;


    public AsyncTaskManager(Context context) {
        myContext = context;
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    }

    /**
     * Executes a task in the background thread, while displaying a busy dialog (non cancellable).
     * 
     * @param task
     *            {@link AbstractProgressableAsyncTask}
     * @param request
     *            request for the background task
     * @param progressLabel
     *            label to be displayed when the progress dialog is being displayed.
     * @param onTaskCompletedListener
     *            {@link OnAsyncTaskCompleteListener} to be notified once the task is completed.
     */
    public <T, P> void executeTask(AbstractProgressableAsyncTask<P, T> task, P request, CharSequence progressLabel,
            OnAsyncTaskCompleteListener<T> onTaskCompletedListener) {
        this.progressDialog.setMessage(progressLabel);

        task.setOnTaskCompletionListener(onTaskCompletedListener);
        //task.setProgressTracker(this);
        task.execute(request);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Progress Handlers
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public void onStartProgress() {
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopProgress() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> list){
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(myContext, R.id.listaPytan, list);
        listQuestions = (ListView)((Activity) myContext).findViewById(R.id.listaPytan);
        listQuestions.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        Log.i("ListView", "Lista wyswietlona");
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727808/android-resource-not-found-exception

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this answer did not help.

Comment: Please debug your code and check error on this line... listQuestions = (ListView)((Activity) myContext).findViewById(R.id.listaPytan); Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, in line to check you requested does not exist any error or warning. Error occurs only after the line:

Comment: startActivity(mainTest);

Comment: i think problem in your TestyActivity class... pls check

Comment: I checked the class TestyActivity errors specified in the request does not appear until after the line [141] startActivity (mainTest); I enclose the entire class TestyActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ArrayAdapter in the following way

`new ArrayAdapter<String>(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)`

instead of

`new ArrayAdapter<String>(myContext, R.id.listaPytan, list)`

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663745/what-is-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1)