# How to fix "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060056"

Tags: android

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwzNy.png)

I tried to set background for LinearLayout, I used code setBackgroundResource() but it has error. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Post your XML file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android resource not found exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727808/android-resource-not-found-exception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to clean and rebuild your project.

If that doesn't work, use this code to set the background

```
linearLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.img1))
```

By the way, next time you should post the code directly instead of passing in a link.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, The program is still error,thank for you reminder

Comment: From the first image you attached, I can see that the img1.jpg file is stored in drawable-v24 folder. It should be stored in drawable folder. Move the img1.jpg to drawable folder and your problem will be gone.

Comment: In case you're new to Android Studio, click on the ```Android option``` on the top of Project tab and change it to ```Project```. You will see a bunch of drawable folders in res folders.

Comment: Thanks bro,I moved the img1.jpg to drawable folder. My problem has repaired

Answer (score 1):

This happens common when you add the resource to another locale, let's say you have two locales, one is `fr` (French) and the other is the default `en`. When you put the image resource in the fr locale and run the app with the default locale, you will see this crash.

Comment: Thank you man, you don't know how much time you just saved me with this comment