# Java: String s = "" + myInteger; - how to mentor away from that pattern?

Tags: java

I am looking for arguments that would allow me to show the light that in Java

```
int myInt = 1;
...
String s = "" + myInt;
```

is indeed a perfectly correct and compiling implementation of `String.valueOf(myInt)` but that doing that "*is not the canonical way it's done in Java*".

"*it looks nicer*" is the argument that I am getting, and "*I expect the compiler to deal with that*".

I have tried sending a link to https://godbolt.org/ (Compiler Explorer) which shows the generated JVM instructions; arguing about "*canonical ways*" or "*least surprise*" or "*implementation patterns*" or "*maintainability*" will not be effective.

I am lost - any suggestions?

Comment: For the record - this is really about *just* converting a plain integer value to String.

If this was in a broader context, going through formatters would clearly be better, and, as far as I can tell, this is also understood.

Comment: Who says it's "not the way that it's done"?

Comment: The *crudest* and most technical argument is: `"" + myInt` results in demonstrably suboptimal code generation for the JVM (and JIT will not be able to repair that)

"not the way that it's done"- to be honest, I have never seen it done in code that I deem of high quality, presumably because of the technical argument, see above.

Comment: "results in demonstrably suboptimal code generation for the JVM" please demonstrate that. It results in _different_ code generation, for sure; it's the assertion that it's practically less good that I'm questioning.

Comment: Whilst you are asking about converting 1 int to a string, consider how your rule should extend to, say, `"" + a + b`: would you write that as `String.valueOf(a) + String.valueOf(b)` (verbose); `String.valueOf(a) + b` (inconsistent); `a + "" + b` (more clear that it's string concatenation, but a bit odd that would be allowed, but not the tokens in a different order); `String.format("%d%d", a, b)` (slow, because of having to parse the format string each time).

Answer (score 4):

In matters of style (and this is a matter of style; *run a micro-benchmark to prove and quantify run-time performance differences*) I would follow these rules:

1. if your project has a style guide that recommends one particular choice, follow the style guide
2. if it has existing code that consistently follows one choice, follow that choice
3. if neither applies, make a choice and stick to it

The source for the JDK is freely available. In Java 8, I count 276 files with one or more occurrences of `"" +` (and in the ones that I looked at, numbers often followed). Of course, there are >3k files with calls to `.toString`, and I have not looked at `.valueOf` at all, so this is hardly conclusive. **Therefore, use of `"" +`  number-to-string conversion does not appear to be uncommon or frowned upon in well-written Java code.**

Not that good Java developers would concatenate strings inside loops; a frequent use seems to be generating error messages for exceptions.

[Oracle's](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) ancient Java style guide, and the more recent ones by [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) and [Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Code-Style) do not appear to have a say on the matter. Therefore, I feel that there is no right answer, and if coding together on a project, and you care enough about this, you should apply Rule 3: iron out a compromise, document it in your project's style guide, and stick to it.

On a personal note, I find `"" + o` easier to read than many of the alternatives, as syntactic sugar for a call to `toString()` that works regardless of the type of `o` (and even when `o` is null).

---

I actually tried this out using [caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper) on JDK 11, **and [results](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/3b7fc90c-4684-4784-9bab-56b204746c0e) show minimal run-time difference, and no memory or object-count difference**, when performing 1k int-to-string conversions by these 3 methods:

```
 t (ms)   method

 12,30    "" + j
 12,57    Integer.toString(j)
 12.58    String.valueOf(j)
```

Code to reproduce:

```
package org.example;

import com.google.caliper.BeforeExperiment;
import com.google.caliper.Benchmark;
import com.google.caliper.Param;
import com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain;

public class Main {

    @Param({"10", "100", "1000"})
    int size;

    private String[] output;

    @BeforeExperiment
    void setUp() {
        output = new String[size];
    }

    @Benchmark void quote(int reps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                output[j] = "" + j;
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark void toString(int reps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                output[j] = Integer.toString(j);
            }
        }
    }

    @Benchmark void valueOf(int reps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                output[j] = String.valueOf(j);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CaliperMain.main(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should perhaps consider contributing the data from this answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653990/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-int-to-a-string: the benchmarks in the top answer are from 2009, and so are very different from yours.

Comment: @AndyTurner good suggestion - my results are very different from theirs, but then again, they did not use an actual microbenchmark, and there are big pitfalls from Not Doing It Right (tm)

Answer (score 2):

In it current form, it is OK, but add a little change

```
    int myInt = 1;
    int myInt2 = 2;
    String s = "" + myInt + myInt2;

    System.out.println(s);
```

vs.

```
    System.out.println(String.format("%d", myInt + myInt2));
```

**is this what you are asking**

Comment: Not sure whether this question is a really good fit for this place (isnt it more code review, SE practices) ... but your answer is great, for sure!

Comment: I would like to point out that my question was about mentoring a person and how to specifically address the case where a single integer was converted to a string.

In a comment to my question I added the note that in broader contexts formatters would apply, but that this specifically was not the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yould show the evaluation happening.

```
String s = String.valueOf(myInt);      // 1

String s = "" + myInt;                 // 1
String s = "" + String.valueOf(myInt); // 2
String s = result of plus;             // 3
```

- `"" + int` is an extra artifact.
- One would also not write `0.0 + n` instead of `(double) n`to convert int `n` to a double.
- The compiler is allowed to generate dumb java byte code:

  ```
    public class IntToString {
        public String intToStringConverting(int n) {
            return String.valueOf(n);
        }
        public String intToStringWithPlus(int n) {
            return "" + n;
        }
    }
  ```

  **javap -c IntToString.class**

  ```
  public java.lang.String intToStringConverting(int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: invokestatic  #7 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
       4: areturn

  public java.lang.String intToStringWithPlus(int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1
       1: invokedynamic #13,  0 // InvokeDynamic #0:makeConcatWithConstants:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
       6: areturn
  ```

As one sees extra code, first calling `makeConcatWithConstants`.

Comment: "The compiler is allowed to generate dumb java byte code" but is this bytecode practically worse? My experiments (rerunning the method described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/654031/3788176 on a much-more-recent Java version) show that `"" + n` actually runs faster (with the standard caveats about "this is not how you write a correct microbenchmark).

Comment: The `"" + <int>` is definitely worse when it comes to the generated code: It is longer. From a real invocation point of view, the JIT engine might introduce optimizations which fold everything down to a simple invocation of Integer.toString(), which is an intrinsic - but that adds load to the JITer.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, in my first edit I formulated it a bit stronger. So you do not seem to agree with the teacher that straight coded is better.

Comment: But the real point is: Why concatenate a string and an integer if the goal is simply "convert this integer to string" - the mentoring aspect.

Comment: @JoopEggen I do not agree: I think either is acceptable.

Comment: @StefanHoffmeister stylistic and pedagogical and even mental I agree with you fully. Unfortunately compilers are the first form of software more intelligent than us.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the form, according to the context. In my experience, I use `String.valueOf()` and `Integer.toString()`. I think the implementation is similar, but I like the second one. Using `String.format`, it's a bit slow because you must parse the expression.

```
int myInt = 1;
...
String s1 = String.format("%d", myInt);
String s2 = String.valueOf(myInt);
String s3 = Integer.toString(myInt);  // I use this
```